# SQLite: Multiple select statements vs one select statement

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android project, I have a SQLite table `data` containing two rows, `id` and `name`. It has +/- ten records. Note that records may have been deleted, so the ids could be non-sequential.

In an activity I need the corresponding names of +/- 100 ids (obviously with lots of duplicate values).

I could do this by executing the SQLite query `SELECT name FROM data WHERE id = x` a hundred times.

Another option is executing the SQLite query `SELECT id,name FROM data` one time, then store the ids and the names in an array, and then get the names of the ids by java (`String name = namesArray[Arrays.binarySearch(idsArray, x)];`

Which method should I use? Or is there even a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is much faster.